Crashing after launch when create new release
I launched the Android TV app on real device and emulator but I didn't get any error
When I make a new release and got a message 'Crashing after launch', i fixed it many times and got same message and rejected status.
Here is mail content from goolge,  i don't know how to fix it!
 `App Status: Rejected Your app has been rejected and wasn't published due to the policy issue(s) listed below. If you submitted an update, the previous version of your app is still available on Google Play.      Issue found: Crashing after launch Your app crashes after launch, which means we cannot review your app for Android TV inclusion. Please refer to our TV Activity documentation for details.  Issue details  We found an issue in the following area(s):  Version code 156: In-app experience About the Android TV App Quality Guidelines We do not accept apps into Android TV that don't adhere to Android TV App Quality Guidelines.`

I wrote class to log error message to remote and crashHanlder wasn't hit

I put crashHandler code in launcher activity
public class TvActivity extends FragmentActivity {
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tv);

    
    Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new CrashHandler());

...do stuff
    }
}
 



public class CrashHandler implements UncaughtExceptionHandler {

    private static final String TAG = "CrashHandler";
    private  boolean _enableRemoteLog = true;

    private UncaughtExceptionHandler defaultUEH;

    public CrashHandler() {
        this.defaultUEH = Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler();
    }

    @Override
    public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable ex) {

        final Writer result = new StringWriter();
        final PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(result);

        // Inject some info about android version and the device, since google can't provide them in the developer console
        StackTraceElement[] trace = ex.getStackTrace();
        StackTraceElement[] trace2 = new StackTraceElement[trace.length+3];
        System.arraycopy(trace, 0, trace2, 0, trace.length);
        trace2[trace.length+0] = new StackTraceElement("Android", "MODEL", android.os.Build.MODEL, -1);
        trace2[trace.length+1] = new StackTraceElement("Android", "VERSION", android.os.Build.VERSION.RELEASE, -1);
        trace2[trace.length+2] = new StackTraceElement("Android", "FINGERPRINT", android.os.Build.FINGERPRINT, -1);
        ex.setStackTrace(trace2);

        ex.printStackTrace(printWriter);
        String stacktrace = result.toString();
        printWriter.close();
        Log.e(TAG, stacktrace);


        if (_enableRemoteLog)
        {
            remoteLog(stacktrace);
        }

        defaultUEH.uncaughtException(thread, ex);
    }

   
    private void remoteLog(String content){
        String url = "https://xxx/log?msg=" + content;
        LogHelper loader = new LogHelper();        
        String[] args = new String[2];
        args[0] = url;
        args[1] = "90";
        loader.execute(args);        
        Log.d(TAG, "remoteLog: " + content);
    }
}


<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  package="xxxx">
<activity
      android:name=".ui.TvActivity"
      android:theme="@style/LightBgBrowse"
      android:exported="true">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_MANAGE_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>


This might not be related to the solution, but, if the code pieces given are exactly as what you have in real app, and not changed just to post here, there is one problem public TKCrashHandler() - if this is supposed to be a constructor, then your class name has to be TKCrashHandler and not just CrashHandler without TK. defaultUEH won't be initialized, and you will get NPE in the last line of uncaughtException method.

@Ishan i type mistake, in my code without 'TK'

Rolling your own exception logging has some non-trivial problems to solve, e.g. making sure the exception handler is in every thread, how to send off the exception log while the app is actively crashing etc... If you don't want to rely on the crash reporting within google play, you could use a ready-made solution like ACRA in your app instead.

In your method
public class TvActivity extends FragmentActivity {
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tv);

    
    Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new CrashHandler());

...do stuff
    }
}

You are calling Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new CrashHandler()).
So, understand the sequence..
First new CrashHandler() will be called.
In that constructor, you are calling this.defaultUEH = Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler().
But, note that the Thread.setDefaultUncaught...() has not been called yet, its parameters are still being built for calling it.  So, defaultUEH will not be set to an instance of CrashHandler. It might be still null or an instance of some other handler set earlier as default.
Then a CrashHandler instance will be returned back to the caller.
Thread.setDefaultUncaught...(ch) will be called with this new instance created.
After this point, Thread.getDefaultUncaught... will return the correct value.
Try doing it like this in TvActivity.onCreate() method:
CrashHandler ch = new CrashHandler();
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(ch);
ch.setDefaultUEH();  // New method which will get the default UEH set by above statement

Add a new method in CrashHandler class:
public void setDefaultUEH() {
    this.defaultUEH = Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler();
}

And the constructor public CrashHandler() {} does not have to be there. The only statement that is there in it should be removed. Entire constructor itself can be removed as it will be a default constructor without any logic.
And from the uncaughtHandler() method, you should remove the last statement defaultUEH.uncaughtException(thread, ex). Because now, defaultUEH points to the same CrashHandler instance itself, so it will keep calling it again and again and will go into infinite recursion.
And, if you actually want to add your own handler as first default handler, let the old default handler also continue in chain, then maybe you can just do the following:
if(defaultUEH != null && !(defaultUEH instanceof CrashHandler)) {
        defaultUEH.uncaughtException(thread, ex);
}

In this case, defaultUEH points to the old default handler if any, or null, if there was none set previously - this is initialized in the CrashHandler's constructor.
And the uncaughtHandler() at the end checks if old handler was there or not, and if it was, it was not the CrashHandler itself (to prevent recursion), and then only continue calling the old handler's routine.

Why do you assume that getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler returns null when it hasn't been set before? Also if defaultUEH is set to the CrashHandler itself, it will recurse infinitely once it handles an exception...

If setDefault...(CrashHanlder) has not been called yet, getDefault... would not return the CrashHandler instance at least, it may not return null, but not the expected CrashHandler instance.

When exception is handled uncaughtException() will be called, that will not instantiate CrachHandler again, so it should not recurse infinitely. That method should just handle the exception, not set default handler again.

Aah yes, I see your point defaultUEH.uncaughtException(thread, ex); is done at the end of the method. So that will call it again and again.

I didn't get any error message from google console when i sent review, but it alway rejected
